# Trying to remove an item from a LazyColumn crashes the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a lazy column that has a list of items, and each one can be deleted. I tried a few things and can't get it to work, it always crashes when I try do delete one.

```
itemsIndexed(state.amounts) { index, cat ->
            AmountItem(cat, onEvent, state, state.amounts.toMutableList(), index)
}
```

---

```
IconButton(onClick = {
        onEvent(NewTransactionsEvent.DeleteAmount(index))
    }) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = "")
    }
```

---

```
_newState.value = newState.value.copy(
        amounts = newState.value.amounts.toMutableList().apply {
            removeAt(index)
        }
    )
```

---

```
data class NewTransactionsState(
val isLoading: Boolean = false,
val date: EpochSeconds = Instant.now().epochSecond,
val payee: String = "",
val type: TransactionType = TransactionType.Expense,
val account: String = "",
val amounts: List<AmountNewTransaction> = emptyList(),
val notes: String = "",
val file: List<FileUrl> = emptyList(),
val error: String = ""
)
```

---

```
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha10")
```

Here's the crash.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.superapps.myfinance, PID: 13363

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3, size 3 at 

androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:183)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:166)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutIntervalContent.getKey(LazyLayoutIntervalContent.kt:86)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl.getKey(LazyListItemProvider.kt:85)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure(LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.kt:46)
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is caused when I have an item after the items composable.

```
itemsIndexed(state.amounts) { index, cat ->
        AmountItem(cat, onEvent, state, state.amounts.toMutableList(), index)
}
item {
   Button()
}
```

if I only have items it works fine.

Thanks :D

Comment: If you're asking for help on a crash, always post the stack trace.

Comment: Are you removing the item from the mutableList or from the state of the lazyColumn?

Comment: from the mutable list, and then i set the list in the state to it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version from the `material3` dependency, [BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom) will provide a compatible version.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
```